# My If function is automatically running the else section and not the main part of the if function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
def SelectingModule():
        OpenFiles2 = open("modules.txt", "r")
        global ModuleInput
        Message = Label(GUIWindows.root, text="please type the ID of the module you want to append").grid(rows=6, column=0)
        ModuleInput = Entry(GUIWindows.root)
        ModuleInput.grid(rows=6, column=0)        
        OpenFiles2.seek(0)

        if ModuleInput in OpenFiles2:
            mylabel1 = Label(GUIWindows.root, text='Module Found')
            mylabel1.grid(rows=9, column = 0)
            AcceptButton = Button(GUIWindows.root, text='Enter ID', command=NewModule)
            AcceptButton.grid(rows=8, column=0)
        else:
            Mylabel2 = Label(GUIWindows.root, text='Not a valid module')
            Mylabel2.grid(rows=9, column=0)
```

So I have a function that just prompts the user to enter a module ID and to have a bit more functionality I have created an if function to check if the data the user entered, exists in the text file. What I want to happen is when the system checks that the id exists in the file (which it does) to display the accept button that will take them to another function. But for some reason the program keeps running the else part of my if function.

[image: here is what's in my text file]

the question is why is my program not seeing that the ID that I entered does exist in the text file?

Comment: ``ModuleInput`` is an instance of ``Entry``, it is not the user input. An ``Entry`` instance can never be inside a text file such as ``OpenFiles2``.

Comment: `ModuleInput` is an instance of `Entry` and `OpenFiles2` is a file object.  So `if ModuleInput in OpenFiles2` will be always false.  Try `ModuleInput.get() in OpenFiles2.read()`.

Comment: Thank you MisterMiyagi and acw1668 that resolved the problem. I am new to programming and I'm still unsure about how instances work but I'll keep studying it. Thanks again